# Entity with LINQ Lambda - unable to grab View into variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to grab data from a View into a Model using Entity LINQ/Lambda. However I am unable to debug the error I'm getting or why it is occurring.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Item
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public List<Review> Reviews {get;set;}
}

public class Review
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public int ItemId {get;set;}
 public string Comment {get;set;}
}
```

And I created a View to grab all items and their respective reviews:

```
Create View ItemReviewView AS 
SELECT 
i.Id AS [ItemId],
i.Name AS [ItemName],
r.Id AS [Id],
r.ItemId AS [TiedItemId],
r.Comment AS [Comment]
FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN Reviews r ON r.ItemId = i.Id
```

The entity model I have for this view looks as follows:

```
public class ItemReviewView
{
  [Key]
  public int ItemId { get; set; }
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<Review> reviews {get;set;}
}

...

//Within DatabaseContext class
public DbSet<ItemReviewView> ItemReviewView { get; set; }
```

However when trying to grab the data from the view using:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

items = _ctx.ItemReviewView.Select(i => new ItemReviewView
{
  Id = i.ItemId,
  Name = i.Name
  Reviews = i.reviews
  .Where(r => r.TiedItemId == i.ItemId)
  .Select(r => new Review
  {
    Comment = r.Comment
  }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

I get the error message:

> Invalid column name 'ItemReviewView_ItemId'

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please define ItemId as Foreign key for Review entity.